# Natural expression for "I hope I'll be of help"?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

Let's say

1. There are some pressing matters at hand

and

2. I want to say I want to/will participate in dealing with those. (together with other people)

From what I've been searching, expressions like "I hope I'll be of help" or such seem to be so ESL I guess? What would a native speaker say in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, "Let me know if I can be of any help." I find this is common enough. It can be amplified for urgency or combined with kinds of help, financial, medical etc.